# How to create new repository without saving old commits in SourceTree?

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I deleted repository from bookmarks, also deleted it from server.

But when I create new repository from my project destination folder it's keeping all the commits I've made in past. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In terminal/bash

you can simply create new repository from terminal :

```
git init
```

Or if you wish to use the old one - delete the git folder and then type `git init`

#### From with in source tree

[image]

And then click on the Create new repository tab
[image]

Comment: For some reason I don't have git folder inside of project folder

Comment: So you still have it locally on your machine. all the git data is in the .git folder, if you delete it you will "lose" all the history of git - its what you asked for

Comment: Yes I want to lose all the history of git but I literally don't have a git folder inside of the project folder

Comment: Cool :-). glad to help